# replicate data from a realtime table to another table in SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, replication

I have a table as RealTimetable and another table as HistoryTable. Now RealTimetable and HistoryTablehave the same structures.  We need a process to replicate the data from the RealTimetable to the HistoryTable, then delete the data from the realtimetable daily.  As the realtimetable cannot grow too big (it causes our application to slow dow tremoundously), but we need to keep all the data from the realtimetable for recording and history purposes, so we keep those data in the HistoryTable.

Triggers and replication are not the best solutions in this scenorio as the the realtimetable get inserted over 60,000 to 100,000 times a day, setting up either would cause a big overhead in the database, no?

I thought of just having a sp to insert the data from realtimetable to HistoryTable daily of data that are not in the HistoryTable, and then delete data from realtimetable after the insert process of data up to say 15 minutes ago (since data might get written to the realtimetable between the the time the insert process and delete process).  We don't want to lose those data..But this is kinda dirty way to do this..

Please suggest me alternate solutions that would work for my scenorio..

Comment: Well, if only you were on 2008 then `MERGE` might be useful :D

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 actually.  I briefly looked up MERGE.  Do you recommend it?

Comment: Hi Tony, I need sql to persist the live data, and we need the live data to generate various daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly reports on thru our SSRS report servers.  Someone mentioned MERGE, would you recommend it?

Comment: It might help with the daily/periodic script to transfer from RealTimeTable->HistoryTable - it's the same idea, just taking care of many of the details and able to take advantage of being a "single statement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to do this, basically you are hacking round a mess, in that you can't keep all the data in one table.

Me I'd start simple and go with move from one table to another jobby, then see how well that does the job, before I started constructing complex algorithms for issues you don't know exist yet.

I wouldn't go with a trigger to populate the history anyway. A slow report on the history table would block an insert into realtime, which is probably the last thing you want.

Have you considered whether sql is the best choice for persisting the live data? If you are "just" battering stuff in there so you don't lose it, you are getting very little out of sql.